# Как вывести TimePickerDialog, соответствующий формату времени в системе (12/24 часа)?

Tags: java, android

Как создать универсальный `TimePickerDialog`, чтобы сам определял формат времени.

Если на телефоне установлено время в 24-часовом формате, то просит при добавлении времени в `TimePickerDialog` в 24-часовом формате - (11:50), если в 12-часовом, то в 12-часовом просит - (11:50 AM)

[image: 24 hour]

[image: 12 hour]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формат времени устройства проверяется с помощью

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
```

Полученный результат можно использовать в конструкторе `TimePickerDialog`

```
public TimePickerDialog (Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
```

или `TimePicker`:

```
yourTimePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context))
```

Comment: `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)`, что возвращает данная строка? ведь в конструктор нужно отправить boolean для определения формата

Comment: Возвращает `true`, если предпочтение пользователя установлено в 24-часовом формате, если  в 12-часовом, то `false`

Comment: `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)` тут `context` это `Context context = null;` или `boolean context = false;` если я его объявляю как `boolean`, то `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)` подчеркивается как ошибка

Comment: Если вы находитесь в подклассе Activity передайте 'this'. Если в своем классе -- передайте `this` подкласса `Activity` в него как параметр или [получите его статически](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android). О  `Context` хорошо написано в документации Android и [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php)

Comment: *`context` это объект класса  `Context`.

Comment: спасибо, помогли))